# Swift: Programmatically set autolayout constraints for subviews don't resize view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have the following setup: A UIView adds a bunch of subviews (UILabels) programmatically, and sets also the autolayout constraints, so that the distance between the labels and between the UIViews edges is 10 each. The goal is that the UIView sets its size accordingly to the content of all the subviews (labels with dynamic text) including the spaces.

I use the following code, but it seems not to work. The UIView doesn't resize, it shrinks the labels.

```
// setup of labelList somewhere else, containing the label data
var lastItemLabel: UILabel? = nil
var i = 1
for item in itemList {
   let theLabel = UILabel()
   // ... label setup with text, fontsize and color
   myView.addSubview(theLabel)
   theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   // If it is the second or more 
   if let lastLabel = lastItemLabel {
        theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        // if it is the last label
        if i == labelList.count {
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.trailingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        }
   }
   // If it is the first label
   else {
       theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
       theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
   }

   lastItemLabel = theLabel
   i += 1
}
```

Comment: Are you adding `myView` to a scroll view? If not, how is it constrained to its superview?

Comment: myView is UIView in storyboard within the main view (outlet)

Comment: Then the question to ask is what constraints do you have on `myView` inside the storyboard? (Forgive me, @Paulw11 already asked this.)

Comment: Make sure you call setNeedsLayout when updating your constraints... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout or layoutIfNeeded https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded

Comment: If `myView` is constrained to the scenes root view then it is never going to get any larger. You will need to use a scrollview.

Comment: Are you programmatically creating and adding each subview?

Comment: @Sneak yes I tried that - it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Paulw11 `MyView` has no constraints. I don't understand why it would require a scrollview. I recreated the setup in a static way in Storyboard, and there it works with the same constraints (and with the `MyView` container without any constraints to the root view)

Comment: You haven't shown what output you are getting, so my assumption was that the text fields cannot fit on the screen without being compressed, hence my suggestion to use a scroll view.  If you can add a screen shot that describes your problem it may help.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just tried to use a scrollview instead of a UIView for MyView, and this works, as the scrollview can be sized accordingly to the screen, and the contentview inside the scrollview can be bigger than the screen determined by the autolayout constraint. Please put this into an answer, then I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need your content to be larger than the physical display of the device, you will need to add a `UIScrollView` to contain your labels.